# JBoss Drools Guvnor to Workbench migration issue

Tags: jboss, drools, workbench, guvnor

We have recently attempted to migrate our rules knowledge base from Guvnor to Workbench.  We are using the drools-wb-jcr2vfs-distribution-6.4.0.Final migration tool to perform the migration.  We have been able to work through enough of the issues to get the first part of the migration to complete which is the export of the jcr, but we are now receiving an error on the import into vfs.  The log files show the following stack trace:

```
15:14:20.910 [main] INFO  o.d.w.jcr2vfsmigration.VfsImporter - VFS import started. Reading from import directory C:\drools-wb-jcr2vfs-distribution-6.4.0.Final\bin\tmp-jcr2vfs.
15:14:20.972 [main] INFO  o.d.w.j.v.ModuleAssetImporter -   Module import started
15:14:20.988 [main] INFO  o.d.w.j.v.ModuleAssetImporter -     Importing module [ProductProcessing] (UUID=e6dfb921-bc91-4bbe-93eb-db1627f86e03)
15:14:22.316 [main] ERROR o.d.w.j.v.ModuleAssetImporter - Exception while importing assets for module 'ProductProcessing'.
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanCDATASection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.drools.workbench.jcr2vfsmigration.vfsImport.ModuleAssetImporter.importAssets(ModuleAssetImporter.java:224) [drools-wb-jcr2vfs-import-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.workbench.jcr2vfsmigration.vfsImport.ModuleAssetImporter.importModule(ModuleAssetImporter.java:179) [drools-wb-jcr2vfs-import-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.workbench.jcr2vfsmigration.vfsImport.ModuleAssetImporter.importAll(ModuleAssetImporter.java:137) [drools-wb-jcr2vfs-import-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.workbench.jcr2vfsmigration.vfsImport.ModuleAssetImporter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.importAll(ModuleAssetImporter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [drools-wb-jcr2vfs-import-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.workbench.jcr2vfsmigration.VfsImporter.importAll(VfsImporter.java:65) [drools-wb-jcr2vfs-import-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.workbench.jcr2vfsmigration.VfsImporter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.importAll(VfsImporter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [drools-wb-jcr2vfs-import-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.workbench.jcr2vfsmigration.VfsImporterLauncher.launchImport(VfsImporterLauncher.java:56) [drools-wb-jcr2vfs-import-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.workbench.jcr2vfsmigration.VfsImporterLauncher.run(VfsImporterLauncher.java:48) [drools-wb-jcr2vfs-import-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.drools.workbench.jcr2vfsmigration.VfsImporterLauncher.main(VfsImporterLauncher.java:33) [drools-wb-jcr2vfs-import-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
15:14:22.347 [main] INFO  o.d.w.j.v.ModuleAssetImporter -     Importing module [defaultPackage] (UUID=1eefd28f-6222-4747-a695-7f22c6d23535)
15:14:22.800 [main] INFO  o.d.w.j.v.ModuleAssetImporter -     Importing module [globalArea] (UUID=c08ab4cc-4c4a-4d55-99eb-771e9553f302)
15:14:23.253 [main] INFO  o.d.w.j.v.ModuleAssetImporter -   Module import ended
```

The error seems to indicate that there is an encoding issue in the modules.xml that was created by the export.  Any suggestions on how to resolve would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the processing instruction on your XML file? Does it name the file's actual encoding? If the first byte of an UTF-8 sequence is invalid, you have some  character > 0x7F that doesn't start a proper UTF-8 sequence but is valid in one or more 8 bit encodings. Frequently `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` helps, but you may have something Windowsy, or weirder.

Comment: The XML file doesn't actually name the encoding.  The first line in the XML starts with `<modules><module><uuid>9b6ef7f2-8b86-4d30-892b-34c119941a29</uuid><type>GLOBAL</type><name>globalArea</name><lastContrib>--</lastContrib><comment></comment><lastModif>1366039568867</lastModif><normalizedPackageName>globalarea</normalizedPackageName><assetExportFileName>9b6ef7f2-8b86-4d30-892b-34c119941a29</assetExportFileName><packageHeaderInfo></packageHeaderInfo><globals></globals><catRules></catRules></module><module><uuid>887b1280-e813-4027-bd7a-873f6ca247f5</uuid><type>NORMAL</type><name>`

Comment: Well, there you are. The XML parser may assume some encoding due to your system's default.

Answer (score 0):

@laune Thanks for your help.  You are correct it was assuming UTF-8.  When I placed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

into each of the XML files that the import job was processing it started working.  I believe it was a Windowsy issue not anticipated by the migration tool.  Thanks again for the help.